# How to make a Turing machine which reads and writes 1s and 0s? C#

Tags: increment, state-machine, turing-machines

So i have a Homework task to create a Turing machine which uses a string like *101* and if it reads a 0 it writes 1 and if it reads a 1 it writes a 0. It uses a Transition rules with states. The full question and the table should be included in the attached image. [The Homework question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sor2j.png)

This is what i've got so far with making this turing machine in C#

```
class Program
{
    enum States
    {
        START,
        ADD,
        CARRY,
        OVERFLOW,
        RETURN,
        HALT
    };
    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        States state = States.START;
        char[] input = "*101*".ToCharArray();
        int index = input.Length - 1;

        while(state != States.HALT)
        {
            switch (state)
            {
                case States.START:
                    if (input[index] == '*')
                    {
                        index--;
                        state = States.ADD;
                    }
                    break;
                case States.ADD:
                    if (input[index] == '0')
                    {
                        index++;
                        state = States.RETURN;
                    }
                    else if (input[index] == '1')
                    {
                        index--;
                        state = States.CARRY;
                    }
                    else if (input[index] == '*')
                    {
                        index++;
                        state = States.HALT;
                    }
                    break;
                case States.CARRY:
                    if (input[index] == '0')
                    {
                        index++;
                        state = States.RETURN;
                    }
                    else if (input[index] == '1')
                    {
                        index--;
                        state = States.CARRY;
                    }
                    else if (input[index] == '*')
                    {
                        index--;
                        state = States.OVERFLOW;
                    }
                    break;
                case States.OVERFLOW:
                    if (input[index] == '*')
                    {
                        index++;
                        state = States.RETURN;
                    }
                    break;
                case States.RETURN:
                    if (input[index] == '0')
                    {
                        index++;
                        state = States.RETURN;
                    }
                    else if (input[index] == '1')
                    {
                        index++;
                        state = States.RETURN;
                    }
                    else if (input[index] == '*')
                    {
                        state = States.HALT;
                    }
                    break;
            }
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: What help do you need?

Comment: Were you told how many asterisks should precede the number? Does a single `'*'` always suffice?

Comment: It should be 1 asterisk before and another at the end otherwise that would cause the overflow state

Comment: Not exactly. The 'overflow' state is not caused by asterisks but by 'carry' overflowing the number, for example incrementing `*1*` (as opposed to successful incrementing of `*01*`). And then the 'overflow' state is handled incorrectly, causing Undefined Behavior. This can be prevented by providing _two_ leading asterisks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.